# I accidentally deleted '/usr/bin/java' file. How to reinstall java?

Tags: java

I typed sudo apt-get purge openjdk*. Now my usr/bin/java file is lost. How can I reinstall java ?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

Answer (score 3):

This link will help you.[Open JDK 8 install](http://openjdk.java.net/install/)

or type in your terminal : $ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre